# Display 10% and have a %s in String.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to display something like this:

> Dear %s, You have 10% left.

Which would result in:

> Dear Johnny Bravo, You have 10% left.

I am using String.format() to format the string for the persons name, but its getting confused with the % in 10% and throwing a MissingFormatArgumentException.

I have tried this

```
10&#37;

10%
```

but both ways throw the exception.

If i totally remove the `%` or `&#37;` then it works fine?

How can I display the % in the text while using String.format

Example Code:

**Java**

```
texview.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.lbl_text), user.getName());
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="lbl_text">Dear %s, You have 10% left.</string>
```

Comment: You didn't say what programming language you're using to display the formatted string, but in some languages, you can either escape the % (using `\%`) or put it in twice (`%%`) to get a literal percent.

Comment: String.format() to format the string for the persons name why?

Comment: can you add some code so that we can get a reference of what you are actually doing

Comment: im sorry, its Java, more specifically Android. I will make the change now

Comment: Thank you, the duplicate worked fine 

Use double %% when you want to just display %.

`Dear %s, You have 10%% left.`